# How to make IF function in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hi i have Four columns in excel
Location Rate OffShoreRate  OnsiteRate

How to write formula for OffshoreRate and OnsiteRate based on Location and Rate

smth like

```
IF location=offshore
than rate=took rate from column rate
If location=onsite
than rate=took rate from column rate
```

[image]

I have an addition. Because the rates will be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your question is bit unclear this generalized implementation of IF in excel may help.

```
=IF(I1="Offshore",J1,IF(I1="onshore",L1))
```

Say you are writing above statement in cell K1 then it will work with respect to cell K1.You can extend it to fill further cells.(It basically tells to fill K1 with value in J1 if I1 reads offshore and so on)